# xmlsecttool vs xerces based XML Schema validation

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I want to know the real advantages of using xmlsecttool for validating,signing XML over writing our own simple Java based XML validator using Xerces JAR?

Why should we prefer xmlsecttool? And is there a way to validate XML against Schema reference mentioned in the XML file itself using xmlsecttool?

Comment: I've never heard of xmlsecttool, and the only hits I get on google are to this question. If it's a thing, then not many people know about it.

Comment: Here are the details -

1. https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/XSTJ2/xmlsectool+V2+Home

2. https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/CONCEPT/MetadataCorrectness#MetadataCorrectness-SchemaValidation.5

Answer (score 0):

Validity checking and signing perform two quite different functions.

Validity checking is about ensuring that the structure of the document conforms to a particular set of rules. If the schema is published, anyone can create a valid document.

Signing (and verification of a signature) are about authenticating that a document is what it claims to be and has not been tampered with. A signature can't be forged.

I know nothing about xmlsectool specifically, but it's claiming to do a very different job from schema validation.

Comment: Okay. Thanks Michael